# How to order by descending with a limit? PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql

Im sure this is a simple solution for you guys, but im trying to just simply select  a table, and order by values called "points". I am only trying to produce the first 5 rows. Here is what I have so far, and its not producing any results.

```
$invcheckquery = "SELECT name , points FROM guild ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5"; 
$invcheck = mysqli_query($con, $invcheckquery) or die("error code : invite already sent!"); 

echo "0";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($invcheck))
{
echo ("\t"); 
echo ($row ['name']);  // The number
echo ("\t");  // The number
echo ($row ['points']);
}
```

Comment: use this query in mysql and see what result you get?

Comment: Your query is fine, which means the problem is with your data, or the PHP script.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks, ill check the error logs again and see what i can gather. Glad to know the query is fine :)